# AngularJS: Accessing controller attributes in a directive's link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, typescript, angular-promise

I'm using TypeScript and creating a controller to pass `rootScope` data to a directive's link function, and while it can return the entire controller, I can't access the controller's attributes. I'm probably missing something pretty obvious, but just can't see it.

## Directive

```
class AnnualPerfController {
    width: any;
    height: number;
    fontSize: number;
    factsheet: boolean;
    values: number[];

    constructor(private scope: ng.IScope, rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService) {

    rootScope.$on('DataUpdated', () => {

        this.factsheet = window.location.pathname.indexOf('factsheet') > -1;
        this.height = this.factsheet ? 260 : 400;
        this.width = this.factsheet ? 250 : null;
        this.fontSize = this.factsheet ? 9 : 11;
        this.values = [
            rootScope['annualizedPerf']['y1_value'],
            rootScope['annualizedPerf']['y3_value'],
            rootScope['annualizedPerf']['y5_value'],
            rootScope['annualizedPerf']['y10_value']
        ];

       });
    }
}

AnnualPerfController.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', "$element"];

export function annualPerformance(): ng.IDirective {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        replace: true,
        controller: AnnualPerfController,
        controllerAs: 'annualPerformance',
        template: '<div id="annual" style="margin: 0 auto">not working</div>',
        scope: {},
        link: (scope, element, attr, ctrl) => {
            console.log('values', scope.$eval(ctrl['values']));
            console.log('ctrl', ctrl);
        }
    }
}
```

What's interesting is the `link` function; the first `console.log` returns undefined, while the second one returns the whole controller like so:

[image: correct output]

Which is exactly what I want. So how do I access the `values` key and its value, for instance?

As a caveat, this is data that is returned from a promise (if it helps)

Comment: why you use `scope.$eval`?

Comment: No reason actually, was just a test. Produces the same result with or without

Comment: first: not needed $eval, next: link called before controller create, that's why you get undefined

Comment: Then how is it returning the whole controller?

Comment: because you expand it after controller was create, and chrome console just  try show actual obect value